# Stubborn resize handle controls on BODY element inside radEditor rich text editor

Tags: css, iframe, resize, handles, radeditor

I have a radEditor which consists of an IFrame that contains an editable 'content area' composed of a BODY element - this is just the standard default implementation of the radEditor control. In Firefox, whenever the user clicks on the content area, resize handles appear around the BODY element, which can then be dragged and/or resized by the user once, after which the resize controls disappear. I don't want the resize controls to appear at all!

After much research and fiddling, I still can't decide if this is a bug in radEditor, a bug in Firefox, a consequence of some CSS inheritance problem, or a problem with the client-side Javascript initialization of the radEditor control.

I have an external CSS programmatically attached which is supposed to be controlling the styles for the radEditor 'content area', but my attempts at changing the resize attribute in CSS in the file are useless, Firefox just ignores the attribute, and firebug does not even show it as being applied, which seems a bit suspicious.

But also, there are a few threads on forums concerning the use of execCommand to disable native resize features, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right lines thinking about this.

Does anybody else have any experience of this issue, or perhaps can give a pointer about what is the most likely area to investigate further? Maybe this is also a problem that has been encountered with other IFrame-based rich-text editors?

Thanks very much if you can help!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this forum thread on the subject: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/disable-drag-and-drop-of-body-element-in-content-area-iframe.aspx

Make sure that you are not importing some css property via the ContentAreaCssFile or CssFiles property of RadEditor that is causing the handlers appearance.